# Vimeo videos should play one after the another

Tags: wordpress

I am using divi theme and there I have added vimeo videos using the video module slider. How I can play the vimeo videos automatically one after the another using video slider module in divi theme?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this, with the help of [Vimeo's Javascript API](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js).

If you have a look at their event section, you will find the "on ended" event handeler. An example could be:

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<script>
    var options = {
        id: 59777392,
        width: 640
    };

    var player = new Vimeo.Player('player', options);

    player.on('ended', function() {

        // Change video id and show your new video
        var options = {
            id: 59777392
        };

        var player = new Vimeo.Player('player', options);

    });
</script>
```

It could be coded up in a more beautiful maner, but this should point you in the right direction. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using divi theme video module and that doesn't play the videos one after the another. It stops after playing one video